# Error starting netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm getting an error starting netbeans because a permission denied access.
I change owner and permissions to ~/.netbeans and the installations folder but I am still getting the same error.

```
sudo chown -R user ~/.netbeans
sudo chmod -R +rw /opt/netbeans
```

What else can I do?

**ERROR log netbeans**

```
!SESSION 2017-06-28 09:34:24.129 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-06-28 09:34:24.129
!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: Permission denied
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the root user, I try the following (changing to the actual user homedir):

```
rm -rf /home/user/.netbeans /home/user/.cache/netbeans
```